# Running a function for specified duration : C++ with <chrono>

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I need to implement a function that should do specified task for specified duration which is passed to it as parameter `(std::chrono::milliseconds)`.

I have come up with code :

```
void Run(std::chrono::milliseconds ms)
{
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    while (elapsed_seconds <= (ms / 1000))
    {
        std::cout << "Running" << std::endl;
        end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    }
}

int main()
{
    {
        std::chrono::milliseconds ms(30000);
        Run(ms);
        system("Pause");
    }
```

I suppose the code to print `Running` for 30 seconds and then exit. But it does not do so. How do I achieve such behavior with `C++ <chrono>`

Comment: `std::future::wait_for` or `std::future::wait_until` maybe would be more appropriate?

Comment: end has no value! could it be the source of your problem?

Comment: @mans Yet another good reason not to declare more than one variable per line **and** always initializing your variables.

Comment: @Yakk elapsed_seconds  showed value in seconds the example I referred, anyways I am trying with `std::future::wait_for`

Comment: `ms / 1000` is 30ms, not 30s as you seem to think. And `elapsed_seconds` is a duration, not a number of seconds. Give them less misleading names like `elapsed` and `total` (not specifying units, since the point of `duration` is to handle units for you), and run while `elapsed < total`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you really need is to know the `end` point and then loop until that point is reached:

```
#include <chrono>

void Run(std::chrono::milliseconds ms)
{
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> end;

    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + ms; // this is the end point

    while(std::chrono::system_clock::now() < end) // still less than the end?
    {
        std::cout << "Running" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::chrono::milliseconds ms(3000);
    Run(ms);
    system("Pause");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the variable `end`.  You fail to initialize it anyhow.

Replace all uses of it with `std::chrono::system_clock::now()` directly.

Use `std::chrono::milliseconds` as your `elapsed_time` -- why convert to seconds needlessly?

```
void Run(std::chrono::milliseconds ms)
{
  std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start
    = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

  auto elapsed_time = [start]()->std::chrono::milliseconds
  {
    return std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start;
  };

  while (elapsed_time() <= ms) {
    std::cout << "Running" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the data operation that you perform.

Have you try to print "elapsed_seconds"?

As explained in the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) you have to do:

```
std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count()
```

By the way, what do you need could be done also with std::future:wait_for as suggested.